# GET Request on Icecast (Traktor Pro 2)

Tags: c#, rest, restsharp, shoutcast, icecast

I want to send GET request on my Icecast stream that is generated by Traktor Pro 2 DJ software. I set up that Traktor sends stream to my localhost on port 8008.

When I try to send simple GET request I always get "Unable to connect to the remote server" msg.

Here is the snippet that I use for sending get request:

```
var client = new RestClient("http://127.0.0.1:8008");
var request = new RestRequest("/",Method.GET);
request.AddHeader("Icy-MetaData", "1");
IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
var content = response.Content; // raw content as string
```

Any solutions?

Comment: Is this Icecast or Shoutcast. They behave differently. Shoutcast is not at all HTTP compliant, while Icecast uses proper HTTP 1.0.

Comment: it's Icecast for sure

Comment: I'm not familiar with C#, but wonder why you are making that a REST request. If it has any special logic for that then it might not work. Icecast will reply to a request with HTTP headers and then a continuous stream of data. Are you sure your stream is on "/"? By default that's the Icecast web interface.

Comment: Also I'd recommend to double check your firewall etc. You could also have a look at the Icecast access.log

Comment: Can you actually see the icecast server when accessing on your browser `http://127.0.0.1:8008` ?